# How to convert 1D vector to 2D vector and user defined rows and columns in matlab?

Tags: matlab, vector

I have a `1x10` 1D vector `A=1:10;` and I want to convert it into a `5x2` 2D vector
is there any function I can use like:

```
2dA = 1Dto2D(A,5,2);
```

and I get

```
2dA = [ 1 2 3 4 5
        6 7 8 9 10]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you are looking for the [`reshape`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html?nocookie=true) function. It works exactly as you have described.